# Issues with npm run test when using absolute imports

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, create-react-app

I have a react application created through the create-react-app cli. I have a .env file where I set `NODE_PATH=SRC` so that all my imports are relative to the src folder. For instance, if the folder structure is like this,

```
-Project
 |      
 +-- src
 |  |  
 +  |-- helper
        |
         +-- Utils.js
```

I can import this file as `import Utils from "helper/Utils"`

But `npm run test` fails with the error

> Cannot find module 'helper/Utils' from 'MyComponent.js'

For a beginner, I couldn't find any solution that I would understand when I googled. And most of them would require ejecting the project. I would like to resolve this without ejecting the project.

Comment: How does your test command look like in the package.json?